# Is it possible to view images in a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, images, ncurses

I have ssh access to my web server. I have some image files there and I would like to see a preview of. Is there a tool that will help me? Is there a curses-based viewer that will approximate the picture?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Oh yes](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aview/)

[image]

If you prefer colour there's [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca)

Comment: I'd +10 this if I could... LOL! Good answer!

Comment: `aview` is awesome! Is there any particular difference between the formats `.p[ngbp]m`?

Comment: @hesse: [about .p{ngbp}m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)  and [converting them to/from jpeg etc](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/directory.html)

Comment: all I can say is YES.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick : Nice, but most screen can display colours today. *(this include ssh and ncurses)*

Comment: @user2284570: [libcaca?](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) (answer updated)

Answer (score 9):

The **`libcaca`** library comes with `img2txt` and `cacaview` tools for this. *In color.*

One can watch movies through it as well:

```
mplayer -really-quiet -vo caca ~/Movies/*
```

Answer (score -1):

there's also fbi if you have frame buffer enabled. IDK if it would work over SSH, but I can view pictures from TTY without having X enabled with it.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because SSH does not have a framebuffer.

Comment: Yeah. I know a lot more about what's going with my stuff than I did over a year ago.